# Why does one npm Module delete other npm modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

This whole  "nvm" - "npm"  fiasco is a disgusting mess.  For one thing, they should have a big flashing red banner at the top of the npm Web-Site that says, "If you intend to do ANYTHING with Node.js, you better decide right now to get rid of the spaces from your folder names."   I never saw any warnings to sanitize my pathnames.   And it didn't help that I tried to go back later and delete those blank spaces out of the path.  As far as npm is concerned, I committed a capital offense with those blank spaces, and I have paid dearly for that error.

For all I know, maybe I am still paying.  Why is it that when you install "nodemon" as a development dependency `npm install --save-dev nodemon` ( as opposed to just installing it globally in a totally separate folder `npm install -g nodemon` ) why does it delete "npm"?  Oh, the npm files are still sitting in the same place that they have always been, but when you go into the Command Prompt and type  `npm -v`   the Terminal acts like he never heard of npm ... like you must be speaking in Russian.

OK, so let's use the Node.js installation executable to "RE-install" the npm that has gone on sabbatical ( actually, the *.msi file calls it "repairing" the installation. )  Now, you get your npm back.  Great.  But now you have a new "npm" folder with hundreds of "node_modules" sitting in a sub-directory of npm.  This is what they call repairing?

But your troubles aren't over yet.  Let's install the very popular npm module: "dotenv" as a development dependency.   This time, the "nodemon" folder ( that you just installed 1 minute ago ) has been deleted, and yes, ( yet again, ) npm has gone fishin'.  That is to say,  `npm -v`  no longer works, even though the npm files haven't gone anywhere.

I would love to know.  How many times am I going to have to re-install npm before I finish writing my first childishly simple Node.js Module?

It's a good thing the npm trash is free.  They couldn't afford to give us our money back.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what the question is Can you more succinctly explain it problem is without editorialising?

Comment: Absolutely, I can.  Here is the question:  why does one npm module delete other npm modules ?

Comment: From the whole speech I didn't see anything about mentioned `nvm`. `nvm` is not working on Windows. Do you use some Node version manager like `nvm` for Windows?

Comment: You are right, I left a LOT of details out of my speech, including the part where I got the instructions on how to use `nvm` straight from Microsoft.  In this video, a guy from France gave a 3-minute tutorial about how to install and use `nvm` that may have worked for him, but it didn't work for me.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_Bb7D7W5LI  Specifically, at 2:32 in the video, when he said that we should use the command `nvm use 12.18.2`, that command was a total fail for me, so I aborted, and tried to go back to the Node.msi installer.

Comment: Here is another example ( yes, I have many more ):  I am in the middle of writing a simple subroutine, and `express` is working fine.  So I go to the Command Prompt and install the popular module `bcrypt` using the command: `npm install bcrypt`   After the installation is complete, `express` no longer works, because the folder that it was sitting in has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I will probably be crucified for answering my own question, but it is working for me.

Here is the bottom line:  Everyone should be able to reasonably expect that when they install a software package, that it is not going to cannibalize other software that they have installed, nor is it going to chew-up their operating system.  But that is what was happening to me with this npm trash.

And if you want to know if you are having the same problem, just run this test:

1. Install npm and Node.js   Then, install about 5 more npm modules of your choice.
2. After the installation is complete, you should immediately UN-install all 5 npm packages, plus Node and npm.
3. After the installation and Un-installation is finished, you should be left with an empty folder.  If the folder has ANYthing left, then your npm modules have been chewing on each other, and spitting out the pieces for you to have to clean up.

That is what was happening to me.  And I suspect that whenever you hear someone on YouTube suggesting that you should install Nodemon 'Globally', my guess is that they are having the same problem that I had, but they don't know how to fix it, so they just push Nodemon off into a different folder where it can't destroy the other modules that they have already installed.

But their "solution" is actually not such a bad idea.  Why not put EVERY npm module into its own separate folder ?  You could sandbox each package, to protect it from other packages that you install later.

To make my solution clear, I will diagram my proposed folder structure.  We start by installing npm and Node:

```
Node
  |
  |__node_modules
```

Now, npm wants you to continue installing all other npm packages into the `node_modules` folder.  But you can force npm to put each npm package into a folder that you get to pick, so that the new structure looks like this:

```
Node-14
  |
  |
  |_____myExpress
  |       |
  |       |__node_modules
  |
  |_____Joi-13
  |      |
  |      |__node_modules
  |
  |
  |__node_modules ( should be NODE ONLY ...
                                nothing else. )
```

Here is the command that will allow you to achieve the outcome above.  In the Command Prompt, you must first Navigate your way into the `Node-14` folder shown above.  Once you are in that folder, type the following command:

```
npm install --prefix ./myFolder npm-package
```

npm will happily create the folder called "myFolder", and then will install the latest version of the "npm-package" that you requested.

And here are a few examples:

```
npm install --prefix ./myExpress express
npm install --prefix ./NodeMon-dev nodemon
npm install --prefix ./Joi-13 joi@13.1.0
```

In the examples above, I added the -dev suffix onto the NodeMon folder name, to signify that this package is for Devlopment Purposes.

Also, the 'joi' example shows you how to intentionally install an old version of an npm package, for whatever reason.

There is one caveat to the instructions that I have given.  I have said that you can choose whatever folder name you want.  That is not 100% true.  If you choose a folder name which is the exact same as the package name, then you run into a problem.  For example,

```
npm install --prefix ./passport passport
```

If you type the command above, then npm will tell you that 'passport' is already installed, and is up to date.

That, of course, is a lie.

Just another example of npm talking trash.

But just to be painfully clear on this issue, in the command below:

```
npm install --prefix ./Passport passport
```

The folder name, 'Passport' is NOT exactly the same as the npm Package 'passport' ( because of the Capital Letter ), so that command will work fine.

In the interest of full disclosure, I must admit that there is a price to be paid for using the installation strategy above:  when you "require" an npm package in the Node.js software that you are writing, it will no longer be short and sweet:

```
const express = require('express');
```

Instead, you are going to have to 'search' for each module individually, because each one is hiding in the sandbox that you placed it in:

```
const express = require ( '../Node-14/myExpress/node_modules/express' );
```

Depending on how deep your folder structure goes, it could easily be even worse that what I have shown.  In some cases, you might even have to go up 2 or 3 levels from where you are sitting:

```
const express = require ( '../../../Node-14/myExpress/node_modules/express' );
```

But in my case, after installing and uninstalling hundreds of npm modules, this was a very small price to pay, for the comfort of knowing that you are not going to be sabotoged by yet another poorly-written pile of trash that acts like a playground bully.

I guess I should also admit that deleting Modules might be a tiny bit more complicated than you are used to.

If you go into the Command Prompt and Navigate to the Node-14 folder ( as you did when you installed the various npm Modules ), and then if you type the customary `npm uninstall <npm-package>`, you can watch while npm furiously fills up your screen with reams of paths and commands, looking like it is actually doing something.

That, of course, is another lie from npm.  In truth, no action was taken.

To uninstall the package, you must Navigate to the Sandbox Folder that you selected, and THEN type the same command.  A couple of examples :

Navigate to the "myExpress" folder, and type `npm uninstall express`

or Navigate to the "Joi-13" folder, and type `npm uninstall joi`

You will be delighted to find that when npm finishes with the un-install process, the folder will be empty, except for an occasional JSON file.  This was a huge change from what I was used to seeing.

Now, you might think that I have gone on and on about npm in this posting, and you might be right.  But the truth is, I have left a LOT out of this answer that there is not room to talk about.

For example, I have another mysterious issue going on with my computer that I have posted in a question here:

[Running the contributed command: 'code-runner.stop' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712487/running-the-contributed-command-code-runner-stop-failed)

I seriously doubt that anyone is going to attempt to answer that question, so I will probably have to answer it myself someday. And I predict, that when I finally find out what caused that bizarre issue that I described in the question, that it is going to have something to do with npm.  That is my prediction, because I have nothing good to say about npm.

Comment: Take a look at: https://npm.community/t/npm-removes-packages-on-install/9432
Perhaps with it, you will change your answer.